# Paypal one-off INVALID ipn?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I've had tens of thousands of IPN notifications from Paypal over the years, and aside from obvious setting-up bugs in the early days, they've all been VERIFIED.

I've had one come through today which is INVALID, and I've no idea why?

I've scoured the request and it looks comparable to all the VERIFIED ones.  There's nothing obviously untoward; no weird characters/glyphs etc.

I went to https://www.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_display-ipns-history and resent this specific IPN and it came through as INVALID again, so it doesn't seem to have been caused by a temporary network glitch.

Any ideas how I can debug this?  The response from Paypal comes with a paypal-debug-id header, but I think that's just for their benefit, I can't find anywhere to do anything useful with it myself?

Thanks

Comment: I have a similar experience. The one transaction that was rejected over a period of many years was from Turkey. I suspect a character-set issue. I reported it to Paypal, as you should, but I was too late for them to be able to review it.

Answer (score 1):

For this kind of issue, since the troubleshooting will require to look at the ipn message ( which contain transaction data ) and settings in your account and website, it is best if you can create a ticket at https://www.paypal-techsupport.com/ and provide all information. PayPal tech support will be able to assist your further.